# Es obligatorio heredar todos los métodos de una interfaz padre a sus hijas: una interfacaz y una clase abstracta

Tags: java

He leído y he intentado ponerlo en práctica, pero no me queda una cosa muy clara. Yo sé que si no heredas los métodos, no ejemplificas las superclases en cualquier ámbito de tipo de superclase (**interfaces, abstractas o concreta**, y la herencia no es problema, la entiendo), porque se supone que sirven para heredar todos sus métodos. Pero qué pasa si tengo esta estructura de clases:

[image: HERENCIA MÚLTIPLE]

> **Interface1**

```
public interface Interface1
{
    int interfaceSuper(int y);
    int interfaceSuper1(int x);
}
```

> **Clase_Asbtracta**

```
public abstract class Clase_Asbtracta implements Interface1
{
    protected int x;
    abstract public int sampleMethodZ(int z); //propia

    @Override
    abstract public int interfaceSuper(int y); //Implementado

    @Override
    abstract public int interfaceSuper1(int x); //Implementado
}
```

> **Interface2**

```
public Interface2 Clase extends Interface1
{
    int sampleMethodJ(int J);//propia
    int interfaceSuperY(int y);//implementado
    int interfaceSuperX(int x);//implementado
}
```

> **Interface3**

```
public interface Interface3//propia
{
    int otherMethod(int y);
}
```

> **Clase_Concreta**

```
public class Clase_Concreta
    extends Clase_Asbtracta
    implements Interface2, Interface3
{
    private int x;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     */
    public Clase_Concreta()
    {
        x = 0;
    }


    /*********************************/
    /*** Sobreescritura de métodos ***/

    @Override
    public int sampleMethodZ(int z){ //Extendido
        System.out.println("implementación");
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int interfaceSuper(int y){ //Implementado
        System.out.println("implementación");
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int interfaceSuper1(int x){//Implementado
        System.out.println("implementación");
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int sampleMethodJ(int J){ //Interface
        System.out.println("implementación");
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int interfaceSuperY(int y){ //Implementado
        System.out.println("implementación");
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int interfaceSuperX(int x){ //Implementado
        System.out.println("implementación");
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int otherMethod(int y){ //Interface
        System.out.println("implementación");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Tengo claro que si todos heredaran todos sus métodos, la class
**Concreta** heredera todos los métodos sino, por lo menos, será abstracta. Pero, ¿Si tengo esta estructura es obligatorio  que las clases **Clase_Asbtracta** y **Interface2** hereden todos los métodos de
**Interface1**?¿o que **Clase_Asbtracta** y **Interface2** hereden los métodos que más me interesen de **Interface1** pero no todos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay que distinguir entre herencia y polimorfismo.

**Una clase en Java sólo puede heredar de otra clase, no hay herencia múltiple.** Por tanto únicamente hereda los métodos y propiedades de una única clase, si bien esta puede heredar a su vez de otra y así sucesivamente. Cada clase hija puede modificar (sobreescribir) los métodos y propiedades de la clase padre, así como incorporar nuevos. Los métodos y propiedades de la clase padre están disponibles en las clases hijas.

El **polimorfismo** es una especie de mecanismo de herencia múltiple, una clase puede implementar varias interfaces, sus métodos son abstractos (no tienen cuerpo) y es necesario sobreescribirlos siempre, entonces "se adquieren" los métodos de varias interfaces, pero estos no tienen cuerpo, lo que obliga a "crear" uno, para cada método presente en cada interfaz.

Para tu diagrama UML observa las flechas, la continua representa una herencia (extends) las otras representan el polimordismo (implements). **Extendido** y **Clase** estan implementando **Implementado**. **Concreta** hereda de **Extendido**, que en esta caso es abstracta, e implementa **Clase** y **Clase2**, con lo que esta obligada a implementar todos sus métodos, y los de **Implementado** que le vienen por la parte de **Clase**. **Extendido** al implementar **Implementado** siendo abstracta no tiene que implementar sus métodos, esto quedará para las clases hijas en el caso de que quieras utilizarlos, así como otros métodos abstractos que pudiera tener.

Un ejemplo de herencia y polimorfismo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el código:

```
package herencia_polimorfismo;
public interface Habitat {

    public String get(); 
}

package herencia_polimorfismo;
public interface Tiempo {

    public void pasarAnios();
}

package herencia_polimorfismo;
public interface Sonidos {

    public String cantar();
}

package herencia_polimorfismo;
public class SerVivo implements Habitat, Tiempo {
    private int edad;
    private int tamanio = 0;

    private void crece() {
        this.tamanio++;
    }

    @Override
    public String get() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public void pasarAnios() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

} //class

package herencia_polimorfismo;
public class Animal extends SerVivo {

    public void alimentar() {

    }

} //class

package herencia_polimorfismo;
public class Pajaro extends Animal implements Sonidos {

    @Override
    public String cantar() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

} //class
```

**Nota:** cada clase y cada interface irá en un fichero independiente.

En cuanto a tus preguntas concretas del bloque:

> Tengo claro que que si
>   todos heredarán todos sus métodos, la class Concreta heredera todos
>   los métodos sino, por lo menos será abstracta, pero, ¿Si tengo esta
>   estructura es obligatorio que las clases Extendido y Clase herede
>   todos los métodos de Implementado o que Extendido y Clase herede los
>   métodos que más me interese de Implementado pero no todos?

La clase **Concreta** hereda todos los métodos de **Extendido**, que es abstracta. Es la única herencia que hay aquí, como tal. La clase **Concreta** no es abstracta, y aunque hereda los métodos de la clase **Extendido**, deberá implementarlos si es que quiere utilizarlos, aunque no estaría obligada a hacerlo, si no va a utilizarlos.

La clase **Concreta** tiene que implementar todos los métodos de las interfaces que implementa, es obligatorio, por tanto tiene todos estos métodos disponibles, con la implementación que haga para cada uno de ellos, lo que "hereda" son las firmas de los métodos.

La clase **Extendido** al implementar la interfaz **Implementada**, "obtiene" sus métodos, puede implementarlos o no (una clase abstracta puede tener tanto métodos abstractos como no abstractos), en este caso no los implementa, pero los sobreescribe, haciendo que sean heredados por **Concreta**, aunque como he dicho, esta hereda métodos abstractos, por lo que no puede usarlos sin implementarlos primero.

Lo mejor sería que cojas el conjunto y hagas pruebas en un IDE para que veas lo que se puede y no hacer.

Comment: Perdona @Orici pero igual no me explique de la mejor forma posible.

Comment: @TripleX los nombres, de las interfaces Clase y Clase2 también acaban de complicar el asunto. Las interfaces no son clases. Si se pudieran cambiar los nombres se podría ver mejor: por ejemplo Interface1, Interface2, Interface3, ClaseAbstracta y ClaseConcreta.